# Need help with this script

Tags: jquery

I am using following script to get Gravatar on my dynamic page,

```
<input type="text" id="email" value="{$clientemail}" style="display:none;"/> 

  $(document).ready(function(){           
                $('.p').append($.gravatar($('#email').val(), {
                method: 'append',
                size: '100',
                image: '/images/1.png',
                rating: 'r'
            }));
        }); 


<div class="p" style="width:100px;height:100px">
```

I have to load value of `{$clientemail}` using following code from another page.

```
$('#email').load('clientarea.php? #clientemail');
```

My problem is **.load** is taking few seconds to load & So **.append** is sending null value, Resulting in default Gravatar pic.

How do I overcome this isuue ??

**Thanks**

Comment: Are you 100% sure `#email` contains a valid E-Mail address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stick the append code in the `load` callback, like this:

```
$('#email').load('clientarea.php? #clientemail' function() {
  $('.p').append($.gravatar($(this).val(), {
            method: 'append',
            size: '100',
            image: '/images/1.png',
            rating: 'r'
        }));
});
```

Though, [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) into an input element like this isn't recommended, it would be better to use a [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) request and grab that value out, like this:

```
$.get('clientarea.php?', function(data) {
  var val = $('#clientemail', data).val();
  //if needed: $('#email').val(val);
  $('.p').append($.gravatar(val, {
            method: 'append',
            size: '100',
            image: '/images/1.png',
            rating: 'r'
        }));
});
```